# Parse string date To GMT date Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Convert String date into GMT date Obj,Then again convert this date into current system zoned date with timezone.using JavaScript Only.

Actually I will response like below.

```
{
"start_date":"2020-02-06 11:23:00"
"end_date":"2020-02-06 11:50:00"
}
```

My requirement is like below.

step:1
'2020-02-06 11:23:10' this string value should be convert Date object with GMT like 'Thu, 06 Feb 2020 11:23:10 GMT'.
step:2
 And again,I want to convert date object into browser timezone DateTime.with format like '2020-02-06 16:53:00+0530'

Comment: new Date().toUTCString(); I tried this but when I am running below the out put.Entered Date : 2020-02-06 11:23:00

Converted Date : Thu, 06 Feb 2020 05:53:00 GMT

Comment: but I want  Entered Date : 2020-02-06 11:23:00

Converted Date : Thu, 06 Feb 2020  11:23:00 GMT

Answer (score 0):

Add **UTC** to the date as `startDate = "2020-02-06 11:23:00 UTC"`. 
Now parse the date as `const localDate = new Date(startDate) //Thu Feb 06 2020 16:53:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.
Browser will parse it localTimeZone based upon timezone of client machine

Comment: But I want output will be the '2020-02-06 16:53:00+0530'

Comment: you can format  date and time separately using ```localDate ..toLocaleString()();```. It would be better to use https://momentjs.com/  ```moment(date).format()``` to get date time in specific format